# What's the simplest way to add water mark using DPP4 that is professional looking?

Tags: photo-editing, digital, watermark

Whats the best but simplest way to add water mark using DPP4?  I cant find anything to create and save watermarks to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Canon DPP 4 put a watermark on a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73123/can-canon-dpp-4-put-a-watermark-on-a-photo) Basically, there isn't one.